# Cannot convert byte to string in EDMX query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008, edmx

i am trying this query in my WPF/C# application:

```
var listaPechatari = from p in pe.Pechataris
    join vp in pe.VidPechatars on p.VidPechatarID equals vp.VidPechatarID
    select vp.VidPechatarIme + " " + Convert.ToString(p.PechatarOznaka);
```

where **pe** is **PrintingEntities** aka my **EDMX** data model.
The problem I get is, **p.PechatarOznaka** is of type **byte(tinyint)** in MS SQL Server 2008. And I get an exception:

```
{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Byte)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}
```

I need to show both the name of the printer and its tag.

Something like **"HP Laser Jet 9000 5"** where the number 5 is of type byte and it is the tag of the printer.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to combine and show both the name of the printer and its tag in a combobox ItemSource?

Comment: Use `p.PechatarOznaka.ToString()` instead of `Convert.ToString(p.PechatarOznaka)`.

Comment: @Evk I get this error when ToString() is used: {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Strange, and what version of Entity Framework is that?

Comment: @Evk I think it is EF 4.x. But i changed it in the my table(in SQL server) to be nvarchar(50) to avoid type conversion.

Comment: Well I don't have much knowledge of such old versions of EF. In EF6, using `p.PechatarOznaka.ToString()` should work fine. You can also try `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(p.PechatarOznaka)`